# Views contextual filter by same Taxonomy Term Name with different Parent

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to filter a view with a path like this  "**/view/%/%/%**" , i'm having a hard time trying to filter nodes that belong to different childs but have the same taxonomy term name. This is the structure :

- Term 1 (Ex Name : "Category grandfather1 test")

  - Term 2 (Ex Name : "Category parent test")

    - Term 3 (Ex Name : "Category child test")
- Term 4 (Ex Name : "Category grandfather2 test")

  - Term 5 (Ex Name : "Category parent test")

    - Term 6 (Ex Name : "Category child  test")

And 2 nodes which belongs to Term 3 and the other to Term 6

When i get the results i always then those who belongs to Term 3 independently of the term that i put before as the parent and grandfather.

I'm using taxonomy term reference tree to load categories , already try auto checking both parent and grandfather.

Could anyone please help me with this ?

pd: sorry for my bad English!